# GCS - Acces data from a software

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, qgis, google-cloud-iam

I setup several services on GCP and I'm learning about how to set read/write permission on each.
I need to use a software, QGIS (geodata), where I need to expose real air photos. I have for 1TB of pictures.

I wanted to expose them with a GCS bucket. I know how to access it via code or URL, but how a software like QGIS can check for the key to have the right to access the data ?

Comment: Would be usefull if you share with us how does this QGIS programm interact with the images, does it read images from a local folder? Can you get images from a drive folder? If this app reads only form a local folder you can use [Cloud Storage Fuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) to mount your bucket on your local machine or in a Compute Engine instance

Comment: I can give a local path. I'm checking if we can have an URL.
FUSE seems interesting but my users are on Windows and this technology seems to work on *NIX system only.